# Converting hex value from string to hext color code

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macros, plist, uicolor

In Objective-C xcode project I have a plist file with which associates integers with hex-color codes. Dynamically I want to use this color-code from plist file and pass that hex value to the following macro to get the `UIColor` object.

**Macro:**

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
 colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

My actual hex value which I need to pass to this macro is 0xF2A80C, but it is present in the plist file. I can get this as a string. How should I do in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Do you want any details regarding this?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
unsigned hex;
BOOL success = [scanner scanHexInt:&hex];
UIColor *color = UIColorFromRGB(hex);
```

Comment: `if (!success) NSLog(@"your hex string is invalid");` There you go!

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
NSString *textValue = @"0xF2A80C";
long long value = [textValue longLongValue];
UIColor *color = UIColorFromRGB(value);
```

I've not tested it. So report me if there are problems.

Comment: Hi Nekto, I tried your solution. But it didn't work. It had shown the color as black always. But Jano's solution worked for me. Anyhow thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the good old C function [strtol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strtol) with 16 as base.

```
const char* cString = [myStr cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
int hexValue = (int)strtol(cString, NULL, 16);
UIColor *color = UIColorFromRGB(hexValue);
```